# Django app crashing in Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first django app on heroku and have been following the guide on the [Heroku site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django).  I get all the way to this step of checking to see if the web process is up and it looks like like the app is crashing:

```
(venv)Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:myportfolio jonathanschen$ heroku ps
=== web: `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`
web.1: crashed for 2m
```

When I check my log there's a lot of stuff.  I've read some of the different posts on stackoverflow and am wondering whether i need to have a proc file in the root directory (there seems to be conflicting answers)?  Could that be whats causing the crash?  As always thanks a lot in advance stack overflow.  Here is the log:

```
(venv)Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:myportfolio jonathanschen$ heroku logs
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 69, in handle
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.run(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in run
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.inner_run(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.db import models, connection
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 34, in import_module
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 7, in _resolve_name
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ValueError("'package' not set to a string")
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: 'package' not set to a string
2012-08-01T18:29:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T18:29:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-01T18:41:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-01T18:41:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:22549 --noreload`
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Validating models...
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     utility.execute()
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in run
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 69, in handle
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.run(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.inner_run(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.db import models, connection
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 34, in import_module
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 7, in _resolve_name
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ValueError("'package' not set to a string")
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: 'package' not set to a string
2012-08-01T18:41:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T18:41:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-01T18:46:00+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-08-01T18:48:55+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by jonathanschen@gmail.com
2012-08-01T18:48:55+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy f097e62 by jonathanschen@gmail.com
2012-08-01T18:48:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-01T18:48:56+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-01T18:48:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:23141 --noreload`
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     utility.execute()
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup()
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myportfolio/settings.py", line 23
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     }
2012-08-01T18:49:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T18:49:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
(venv)Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:myportfolio jonathanschen$ heroku ps
=== web: `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`
web.1: crashed for 1m

(venv)Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:myportfolio jonathanschen$ heroku ps
=== web: `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload`
web.1: crashed for 2m

(venv)Jonathans-MacBook-Air-2:myportfolio jonathanschen$ heroku logs
2012-08-01T18:29:55+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: 'package' not set to a string
2012-08-01T18:29:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T18:29:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-01T18:41:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-01T18:41:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:22549 --noreload`
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Validating models...
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     utility.execute()
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in run
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 69, in handle
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.run(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.inner_run(*args, **options)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 23, in get_validation_errors
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     from django.db import models, connection
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     return import_module('.base', backend_name)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 34, in import_module
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 7, in _resolve_name
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise ValueError("'package' not set to a string")
2012-08-01T18:41:46+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: 'package' not set to a string
2012-08-01T18:41:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T18:41:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-01T18:46:00+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-08-01T18:48:55+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by jonathanschen@gmail.com
2012-08-01T18:48:55+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy f097e62 by jonathanschen@gmail.com
2012-08-01T18:48:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-01T18:48:56+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-01T18:48:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:23141 --noreload`
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     utility.execute()
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup()
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myportfolio/settings.py", line 23
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2012-08-01T18:48:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     }
2012-08-01T18:49:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T18:49:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-01T19:03:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-01T19:03:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:20934 --noreload`
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     utility.execute()
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._setup()
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in __init__
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/myportfolio/settings.py", line 23
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2012-08-01T19:03:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     }
2012-08-01T19:03:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-01T19:03:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and when looking at the logs (heroku logs) it turned out that it couldn't find the module psycopg2.

Adding psycopg2==2.4.5 to the requirements.txt file solved it

Comment: Or now psycopg2==2.7.4  Probably best to check Pypi for latest version.  I had another problem as well

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and the problem was a syntax error in the settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and figured it out after a lot of issues.

I noticed that running pip freeze > requirements.txt was leaving out a few required items from the file.

Of note were these two:

whitenoise==1.0.6
wsgiref==0.1.2

You can find what absolutely needs to be in there by going here:

[Heroku Django Template -- requirements.txt](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template/blob/master/requirements.txt)