# Heroku, Django app crashing on startup, "not a valid port number"

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to run my first Django powered app on Heroku. I have been following [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django). The app is running fine using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

When I commit any changes I made, and then try to push it to Heroku, everything seems fine until I visit the heroku URL. I receive an 'Application Error' page. Looking more in to the:

```
heroku logs
```

I get a bunch of what appears to be the same error message:

```
.......
2013-01-18T05:28:29+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-01-18T05:28:29+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: "0.0.0.0:" is not a valid port number        or address:port pair.
2013-01-18T05:28:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-18T05:28:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python      manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0: --noreload`
2013-01-18T05:28:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: "0.0.0.0:" is not a valid port number or     address:port pair.
```

Also if I do a foreman start:

```
22:39:26 web.1  | started with pid 2499
22:39:26 web.1  | Error: "0.0.0.0:" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.
22:39:26 web.1  | exited with code 1
22:39:26 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

I looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765945/django-app-crashing-in-heroku) but I seem to have everything needed in my requirements.txt file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have something strange in your `Procfile`.  Examine your `Procfile` and either follow the Heroku instructions for setting up gunicorn (recommended for production), or else add a port number -- presumably `80` -- to your `Procfile` as so:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80 --noreload`

Comment: Thanks - I ended up solving this, I had the port number wrong. I ended up using gunicorn anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Heroku** and Docker I got the same error but I was using the `$PORT` environment variable.

For some reason the port number had a backslash (`\`) as in `\80`. So I had to remove it:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${PORT##\\}
```

For future reference, in case someone stumbles upon this question as I did in hope this helps.